# Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump" error on Android and OWT versions 4.3.1 and 5.0

Tags: android, webrtc, video-streaming

Find this bug on some Android devices, for example:

- Lenovo TB X606X, Android 10
- Meizu M570H, Android 6
- Redmi 9, Android 10q

When try to start stream with OWT Framework versions 4.3.1 or 5.0 got this in logs -

I/BufferQueue: unnamed-17090-3 BufferQueue core=(17090:xxxx)

E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"

I/BufferQueueConsumer: unnamed-17090-3 connect(C): consumer=(17090:ru.etreta.a2aw) controlledByApp=true

E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"

I/BufferQueueConsumer: unnamed-17090-3 setConsumerName: unnamed-17090-3

E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"

I/BufferQueueConsumer: SurfaceTexture-1-17090-3 setConsumerName: SurfaceTexture-1-17090-3

W/CT: type=1400 audit(0.0:1893): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=6770 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c161,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

I/org.webrtc.Logging: CameraCapturer: startCapture: 1280x720@24

I/org.webrtc.Logging: Camera1Enumerator: getCameraIndex: Camera 0, Facing back, Orientation 90

I/org.webrtc.Logging: Camera1Session: Open camera 0

I/org.webrtc.Logging: SurfaceViewRenderer: full_renderer: onMeasure(). New size: 1200x1896

I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: full_renderersetLayoutAspectRatio: 0.6329114

D/OWT: create offer

D/Camera-JNI: (tid:18375)[MtkJNICameraContext] this:0x75a84afae0 camera->getStrongCount(3)

I/org.webrtc.Logging: Camera1Session: Available fps ranges: [[10.0:10.0], [15.0:15.0], [15.0:20.0], [20.0:20.0], [5.0:30.0], [30.0:30.0]]

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-15-thread-1

Any suggestions how to fix it? Both for debug or release

Comment: I'm also getting this, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

These devices do not support H264 codec. Switch to VP8/9 makes them work.